# Как изменить автоматическое создание реплицируемых таблицы в Symmetric?

Tags: java, mysql, база-данных

```
CREATE TABLE users (
  id INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  name VARCHAR(45) NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (id));
```

Я испульзую Symmetric 3.10 для репликации таблицы  users, с slave в master. Symmetric автоматически создаёт копию таблицы из slave на master, как мне повлиять на это чтобы таблица на master выглядила вот так:

```
 CREATE TABLE users (
      master_id INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
      id INT,
      name VARCHAR(45) NULL,
      PRIMARY KEY (id));
```

То есть мне нужно чтобы на master был свой первичный ключ.

```
          slave.users  ----sync--->>  master.users

          []   ---------------------->> [master_id = 1 primary key] 
          [primary key id = 11] ----->> [id_users = 11]
          [name = Bob]  ------------->> [name = Bob]
```

Comment: Это уже будет не репликация, а синхронизация...